# I Cannot clone a git repository

Tags: git, repository, clone

I am trying to clone a git repository from our corporate git server and get:

```
Cloning into 'C:\git\<name_of_repository>...
fatal: unable to access '<corporate_git_server_url>/<name_of_repository>.git/': schannel: CertGetNameString() failed to match connection hostname (<corporate_git_server_url>) against server certificate names.
```

Obviously there is some issue with certificate, but I do not know where to look. Also it is strange as my colleagues successfully checked out the repository.

Comment: Can you provide us with the full command you're using to clone the repo (obviously redact any sensitive info)

Comment: i try to do this using the github desktop application

Comment: Do you use GitHub for Desktop? (not command line)

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error pushing to a repo on visualstudio.com.

As it implies, there's some sort of an issue with schannel getting the certificate information.

Apparently [you can change git's https transport](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/2514). I changed mine from schannel to openssl and it fixed the issue.

```
>git config --global http.sslBackend "openssl"
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I was getting the `schannel` error on trying to check out a project through GitHub Enterprise through the desktop client. Updating the global  .gitconfig fixed it. This should be the accepted answer.